# Get constant fields from a class using RTTI

Tags: delphi, rtti

Can I enumerate the constants(const) from a class?

I have tried

```
MyClass = class
const
  c1 = 'c1';
  c2 = 'c2';
  c3 = 'c3';
end;

procedure GetConst();
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  objType: TRttiType;
  field: trttifield;
  s: string;
begin
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  objType := ctx.GetType(MyClass.ClassInfo);
  for field in objType.GetDeclaredFields do
    s:= field.Name;
end;
```

I would like to get c1, c2, c2.

Is this possible?

edit:
what I want to do is define some keys for some external symbols(for a cad program)

```
symbol1=class
    const
    datafield1='datafield1';
    datafield2='datafield2';
end;
symbol2=class
    const
    datafield21='datafield21abc';
    datafield22='datafield22abc';
end
```

I don't like to use fields for this because I prefer not to seperate declareration and initialization.
I can't use an enum since I can't define the value as a string.

Comment: probably not. Probably at compile time there are no more constants but the immediate values instead. there is little sense to kkep them separately

Comment: If you did an enum, you could add `TypInfo` to your `uses` clause and then use `GetEnumName` and `GetEnumValue` to translate between the string and ordinal values.

Comment: but enum value can only be integer right? I need string

Comment: `GetEnumName` translates the `int` to a `string`.  `GetEnumValue` translates a `string` to the enum `int`.  So even though an enum is a series of `int`s, you can use them in your code like strings.

Comment: I'll add an example as an answer so you see how to translate an enum to a string and back to an enum...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get at those constants through RTTI. I suspect your best solution will be to use attributes instead. Not only will that have the benefit of actually working, I think it sounds like a cleaner and simpler solution to your problem.

Comment: Attributes on what exactly? What should they contain?

Comment: Attributes on each class that contain its keys.

Answer (score 4):

If you use an enum, you can use `TypInfo` to translate strings to the enum values, and the enum values to strings in your code:

```
type
  TDataFieldName = (datafield1, datafield2, datafield3);

uses TypInfo;

var df: TDataFieldName;
begin
  df := TDataFieldName(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TDataFieldName), 'datafield1'));

  ShowMessage(GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TDataFieldName), Ord(df)));

  case df of
    datafield1:;
    datafield2:;
    datafield3:;
  end;
end;
```

(Typed from my head -- haven't tested this...)

This way the cad program can pass strings to your Delphi app, and you can translate them to the enum, or you can translate the enum to a string to pass to the cad program.  It's also easy to do a `case` statement where the original value was a string, converted to an enum.  This has come in very handy since Delphi doesn't support `string` case statements.

Comment: Does RTTI impose much overhead in this situation as compared to say var fields in a class? Is there a common base type for enums so I can make a common method to handle symbol1 and symbol2

Comment: I've never analyzed the RTTI overhead -- but I commonly use this so that I can use a `case` statement with the string converted to an enum (see edit above).  I've never had any performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use fields in my classes. Since I don't want to duplicate fields for declaration and initialization, i'm using rtti to initialize fields to the value of the field.

The benefits are: No rtti overhead on runtime. rtti is only performed during app startup. Also I get to use inheritance which is very useful for my project.

Comment: That's nice. Glad that you have a solution. However, this is not an answer to the question that you asked. Remember that you asked if RTTI could be used to obtain class constants.

Comment: Regarding solutions to your problem as opposed to answers to the question you asked, did you consider a method call to retrieve these field names? This would likely be a virtual class method if you have a common ancestor. Otherwise it would probably need to be an interface.

Comment: I may not have communicated this clearly, but I need to be able to enumerate and have keys readily available like key1.field1. I could add a method to use rtti, but seems like a detail.