# Accessing Class Constants from a Class Reference variable in Delphi

Tags: delphi, inheritance, constants, class-constants

I'm using Delphi 2007 to maintain an old project, I have a problem accessing class constants from a Class Reference variable, I get always the parent class constant instead of the children one.

Suppose to have a parent class, some child classes, a class reference and finally a const array to store the class references for looping purposes.

take a look at following simple program:

```
program TestClassConst;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type

  TParent = class
  const
    ClassConst = 'BASE CLASS';
  end;

  TChild1 = class(TParent)
  const
    ClassConst = 'CHILD 1';
  end;

  TChild2 = class(TParent)
  const
    ClassConst = 'CHILD 2';
  end;

  TParentClass = class of TParent;
  TChildClasses = array[0..1] of TParentClass;

const
  ChildClasses: TChildClasses = (TChild1, TChild2);

var
  i: integer;
  c: TParentClass;
  s: string;

begin
  try
    writeln;

    writeln('looping through class reference array');
    for i := low(ChildClasses) to high(ChildClasses) do begin
      c := ChildClasses[i];
      writeln(c.ClassName, ' -> ', c.ClassConst);
    end;

    writeln;

    writeln('accessing classes directly');
    writeln(TChild1.ClassName, ' -> ', TChild1.ClassConst);
    writeln(TChild2.ClassName, ' -> ', TChild2.ClassConst);

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

When it runs I get:

```
looping through class reference array
TChild1 -> BASE CLASS
TChild2 -> BASE CLASS

accessing classes directly
TChild1 -> CHILD 1
TChild2 -> CHILD 2
```

I expected to see 'CHILD 1' and 'CHILD 2' also in array loop!

Can anyone explain me why it does not work with class reference?

Comment: You need a virtual method to implement polymorphism.
.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An untyped class constant is a normal constant with some scoping added.
A typed class constant is really a class variable that you cannot change.
The problem is that the class variables are not virtual.

Hallvard Vassbotn has written about this issue here: [Part 1](http://hallvards.blogspot.nl/2007/05/hack17-virtual-class-variables-part-i.html), [Part 2](http://hallvards.blogspot.nl/2007/05/hack17-virtual-class-variables-part-ii.html)

You cannot access class variables and class constants from a class reference because the language does not have support for virtual class variables.
When you say `s:= TClass1.SomeConst` the compiler translates this into `s:= SomeGlobalButHiddenConst` before moving on with the rest of the compilation.

`class var` and `class const` are nothing more than syntactic sugar.
As such the link between the `class var/const` and the actual class only exists during compile-time, it is broken come run-time, much like type-erasure in Java.

RTTI also does not help: [Get constant fields from a class using RTTI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531178/get-constant-fields-from-a-class-using-rtti)
I guess if you're using D2007 your only option is to declare a virtual function that returns the constant you want:

**Pre D2010 option: virtual method**

```
TParent = class
  class function Name: string; virtual;
end;

TChild1 = class(TParent)
  class function name: string; override;
....
class function TParent.name: string;
begin
  Result:= Self.ClassConst;
end;

class function TChild1.name: string;
begin
  Result:= Self.ClassConst;   //Silly copy paste solution
end;
```

This is a sad state of affairs, but I don't see another option.

**[From Delphi 2010 onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460037/list-of-delphi-language-features-and-version-in-which-they-were-introduced-depre): use [attributes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Attributes_Index)**
A better option is to use attributes, these you can access using [RTTI](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Working_with_RTTI_Index):

The following code works:

```
program TestClassConst;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, rtti;

type

  NameAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
  private
    Fname: string;
  public
    constructor Create(const Name: string);
    property Name: string read Fname;
  end;

  [Name('Base class')]
  TParent = class
  const
    ClassConst = 'BASE CLASS';
  private
  public
    class function Name: string;
  end;

  [Name('Child 1')]
  TChild1 = class(TParent)
  const
    ClassConst = 'CHILD 1';
  end;

  [Name('Child 2')]
  TChild2 = class(TParent)
  const
    ClassConst = 'CHILD 2';
  end;

  TParentClass = class of TParent;
  TChildClasses = array[0..1] of TParentClass;

const
  ChildClasses: TChildClasses = (TChild1, TChild2);

var
  i: integer;
  c: TParentClass;
  s: string;

{ TParent }

class function TParent.Name: string;
var
  Context: TRttiContext;
  ClassData: TRttiType;
  Attr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  Context:= TRttiContext.Create;
  ClassData:= Context.GetType(Self);
  try
    for Attr in ClassData.GetAttributes do begin
      if Attr is NameAttribute then Result:= NameAttribute(Attr).Name;
    end;
  finally
    ClassData.Free;
  end;
end;

{ NameAttribute }

constructor NameAttribute.Create(const Name: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FName:= name;
end;

begin
  writeln;

  writeln('looping through class reference array');
  for i := low(ChildClasses) to high(ChildClasses) do begin
    c := ChildClasses[i];
    writeln(c.ClassName, ' -> ', c.Name);
  end;

  writeln;

  writeln('accessing classes directly');
  writeln(TChild1.ClassName, ' -> ', TChild1.Name);
  writeln(TChild2.ClassName, ' -> ', TChild2.Name);
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: thank you Johan, the subclassed class function solution works like a charm.
Very interesting also the Hallvard Vassbotn post. 
I can't imagine this was a so old problem.. and still unresolved! :D

Comment: @MtwStark, now that we have attributes the problem has largely gone away.